# Why C# list was implemented using array and not a linked list

Tags: c#, list, collections

I went over the code of a List in C#

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

why is the list implemented as an array and not as a linked list?

I know memory is an issue when using for example double linked list comparing to an array, however when you remove/add a node to a list you will have less of a performance impact.

Can you please explain?
Thanks

Comment: How would you access linked list by index?

Comment: Among other reasons: It was meant to (generically) replace ArrayList.

Comment: I want to add and remove items, that is the goal of list without a limitation of space, i.e I don't have to resize all of the time, like in arrays. yes accessing to data is important but also removing and adding, I want to iterate of the list, not only access by index.

Comment: @OrelEraki thanks I wan't able to find it.

Comment: Look especially at Hans's remarks; they actually do answer the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is a [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#.

As for differences between array and linked list, an array provides fast and random access to the element in collection while in linked list, elements can’t be accessed randomly but can be accessed only sequentially and accessing element takes 0(n) time. Though there are some advantages of using LinkedList instead. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist) provides detailed comparison.